# Merge two counterpart filtered SQL query as one

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which uses a set of complex conditions, but need control whether to filter or counter filter on the conditions. I use `@bool BIT` to control the flow (ignore case `@bool=NULL`):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE someSP @bool BIT AS

IF @bool = 1
  SELECT cols
  FROM table
  WHERE <common conditions>
  AND (
  <Some complex conditions, which frequently changing per business request>
  )
ELSE
  SELECT cols
  FROM table
  WHERE <common conditions>
  AND NOT (
  <Same complex condition. Code must keep same as the previous one>
  )
```

The actual query is very long, so I want to merge the two queries into one due to maintenance and aesthetic purposes. But as you know, the `WHERE` conditions in SQL cannot be written as common language like `if(!bool ^ isComplexConditionMet)`, so I wonder if there is alternative ways to merge the code into one.

Dynamic query using `CASE WHEN @bool=1 THEN '' ELSE 'NOT ' END` is a solution, but it makes code difficult to read. but wonder if any ones better?

Comment: Its trivial and/or logic.... `where (@bool = 1 and <some conditions>) or (@bool = 0 and <some conditions>)`

Comment: @Dale K My concern is if `<some conditions>` are 100 lines long and 2000 chars wide making reading code frustrated and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Don't merge them then :)

Comment: If you want to toggle the `NOT` keyword this can only be done with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temp table to make it more readable.
Something like this e.g.:

```
SELECT cols 
INTO #result
FROM table1 t1
WHERE<common conditions>

ALTER TABLE #result
ADD complexConditions bit

UPDATE #result
SET complexConditions = 1
WHERE <complex condtition>

SELECT *
FROM #result
WHERE complexConditions = @bool
```

Comment: Its a good approach. but it doesn't cover the case that the `cols` used in `<complex condition> does not appear in the `cols`. I myself found a better one, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I myself found a good approach, makes `XOR` logic working:

```
WHERE <common conditions>
AND CASE WHEN <Same complex condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + @bool = 1
```

`@bool` value needs reverse defined to the question, and might need converting into int depend on server version.